# Facebook Opengraph action publishing error

Tags: facebook, action, publish, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create a read button for my application. I have implemented the code as per the tutorial, but when i click publish button it says Error Occurred

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function postArticle()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/svolzesocial:news.reads?article=<?php the_permalink() ?>',
        'post',
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
  </script>
```

I also tried debugging, but its showing no error there.
I have created publish button on this page [Svolze post](http://fb.svolze.com/2012/03/14/hello-world/) Please help me out to sort this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're posting to the wrong URL.

If you're using the build in read action you should post to

```
/me/news.reads
```

If you're using a custom action you should post to

```
/me/yournamespace:youractionname
```

At the moment, you're convoluting the two.

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil,

Please also console.log(response) when there is an error to help debug. My guess is that you don't have the correct permissions - you will need publish_actions to publish on the user's behalf. Add a [login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) with the correct scope and then try to publish.

Some resources:

[Perms page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)
[Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)